# How can I find what external S3 buckets (AWS-owned) are being accessed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using WorkSpaces Web (not WorkSpaces!) with an S3 VPC endpoint. I would like to be able to restrict S3 access via the S3 endpoint policy to only the buckets required by WorkSpaces Web. I cannot find any documentation with the answers, and AWS support does not seem to know what these buckets are. How can I find out what buckets the service is talking to? I see the requests in VPC flow logs, but that obviously doesn't show what URL or bucket it is trying to talk to. I have tried the same policy used for WorkSpaces (below), but it was not correct (or possibly not enough). I have confirmed that s3:GetObject is the only action needed.

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Access-to-specific-bucket-only",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-windows-downloads-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::amazon-ssm-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::amazon-ssm-packages-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::us-east-1-birdwatcher-prod/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-ssm-distributor-file-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::aws-ssm-document-attachments-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::patch-baseline-snapshot-us-east-1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::amazonlinux.*.amazonaws.com/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::repo.*.amazonaws.com/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::packages.*.amazonaws.com/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```